# mongodb sort order on _id

Tags: mongodb

I wonder how mongodb compare the "_id" field when doing query like the following:

```
db.data.find({"_id":{$gt:ObjectId("502aa46c0674d23e3cee6152")}}).sort({"_id":1}).limit(10);
```

Is it purely based on timestamp portion of the id?

Answer (score 74):

To expand slightly on what Andre said:

Since the ObjectID timestamp is only to the second, two (or more) ObjectIDs could easily be created with the same value for the timestamp (the first 4 bytes).  If these were created on the same machine (machine ID - the next 3 bytes), by the same process (PID - the next 2 bytes), then the only thing to differentiate them would be the "inc" field, the last 3 bytes at the end.

**Update: Jan 2020**

This answer continues to be popular so it is worth updating a little. The ObjectID spec has evolved since this answer was written 8 years ago and the 5 bytes after the timestamp are now simply random, which will greatly decrease the likelihood of any collisions. The last three bytes are still incremental, but initialised at a random value to start, again making collisions less likely. The ObjectID now contains less context (you can't easily tell where it was generated and by what process) but I would guess that the information was not being used in any meaningful way and has been deprecated in favor of better randomisation of the ID.

**End Update**

See here for the full spec:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification

That "inc" field is either an ever incrementing field (then you can reasonably expect the sort to be in the insert/create order) or a random value (then likely unique, but not ordered), assuming the spec is implemented correctly of course.  Note that the ObjectIDs may be generated by the driver, or the application (or indeed manually) rather than by MongoDB itself, so unless you have full control over how they are generated, then any or all of the above may apply.

Comment: Since it is generated by the app, technically (pureist here) it is never sorted by insertion but rather when the driver applied the _id to the document.

Comment: Since we are noting the technicalities, the _id is generated by the app, if it, or the driver (or you) specify it client side.  If no _id is passed as part of the document on insert, then the _id is generated by the server, so it is not always when the driver applies it to a document.

Comment: Which is better `ObjectId` or `auto increment` primary key, when we have to sort on that column, in mongodb?

Comment: ObjectId is the default and there are several optimisations for it in the code base. I haven't tested though, and I expect the differences would be small, but if I were to make an educated guess I go for ObjectId over an auto-incrementing field

Comment: I don't know who or if anybody needs to know this, **find() in mongodb doesn't guarantee that documents returned would be the same order as they were inserted. Or sorted by _id** You need to specify the sort explicitly, if needed.

Comment: The question does explicitly specify the sort in this case `.sort({"_id":1})`

Comment: for me this design to start with is a fundamental flaw in the system. I am wondering how Mongo became so popular?

Comment: @chendu you know you can just create your own field (or use a UUID for example) and not use ObjectId right? It's not a requirement, just a useful built-in option that is used by default.

Answer (score 36):

In a way you are correct, if you sort by the `_id` you will sort by the insertion time.  This does not mean that the only comparison is done on the timestamp portion.  ObjectID's are a BSON object type in their own right, they can be directly compared with each other.  As they start with a timestamp, it follows logically that those in the past will be less than those in the future.

You can find more detail in the [documentation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs#OptimizingObjectIDs-Sortbyidtosortbyinsertiontime)

Answer (score 19):

copy paste from Mongo specs
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid

**The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and generation time is not strict within a single second**. If multiple systems, or multiple processes or threads on a single system generate values, within a single second; ObjectId values do not represent a strict insertion order. Clock skew between clients can also result in non-strict ordering even for values, because client drivers generate ObjectId values, not the mongod process.