# Sorting on _id gives inconsistent results

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have something weird, I try just to sort on _id and have some paging. Hereunder you will see the query I execute:

```
var condition = { isArchived: false };
if(lastId) {
    condition["_id"] = { $lt : lastId };
};

PostModel
    .find(condition)
    .sort({_id:-1})        
    .limit(10)
    .exec(function (err, posts) {
        if(err)
            return callback(new customError.Database(err.toString()),null);

        callback(null, posts);
    })
```

What I see is that in 80% of the time the result is consistent, but sometimes the result is not the same (it does not vary much, but some objects are in a different order).

I use this technique with success on other models, but only with this query/collection I get this problem (not sure if the problem is in the query or on the collection...)

What can be the reason?

Comment: is your `_id` on ObjectId hexadecimal ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098815/mongodb-sort-order-on-id

Comment: yes it is, but even then why would the sort order change? I understand it is not the best way to do sorting, or that the sort order does not have any "real" meaning, but I don't understand that when I execute several calls, the sort order is different in some of the cases